# Android Studio won't render my activities

Tags: android, android-studio

Android Studio straight crapped out on me tonight. I went to open my project and now I can't use the activity UI. Two different errors:

**activity_main.xml**

```
The following classes could not be found:
- android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout (Fix Build Path, Edit XML, Create Class)
 Tip: Try to build the project.
```

**settings_activity.xml**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.isThemeAppCompat(RenderSessionImpl.java:1203)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.findStatusBar(RenderSessionImpl.java:1066)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.init(RenderSessionImpl.java:209)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:319)
at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:350)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:497)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:485)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:894)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:485)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.render(RenderTask.java:590)
at com.intellij.android.designer.designSurface.AndroidDesignerEditorPanel$6.run(AndroidDesignerEditorPanel.java:480)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:320)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:310)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue$2.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:254)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:269)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:227)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:217)
at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:238)
at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1.run(Alarm.java:351)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The second error I have no clue about, but the first one is really weird to me. I've already imported `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.0` in the Dependencies, and the application deploys fine in both debug and release environments.

Thoughts?

**Edit**: Per suggestion, I can render my main activity using API 21. However, my settings activity still won't render the new error is:

```
Missing styles.
Is the correct theme chosen for this layout?
Use the Theme combo box above the layout to choose a different layout, or fix the theme style references.
Failed to find style 'textViewStyle' in current theme (2 similar errors not shown)
```

**Edit 2**: I managed to fix the second issue by just selecting a different theme from the list and then selecting back onto my AppTheme. Not sure why I needed to do that, but whatever. Aside from my Switch element being completely black, it renders just fine now.

Comment: Have you imported your existing eclipse project to Android Studio?

Comment: @user2163887 I made the project in Android Studio originally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all build project, then change "android version to use when rending layouts" to lower (design screen-> top panel->icon with android).

also it can't rending custom view

Comment: My main activity will display when using API 21, not 22, which is helpful. But my settings activity still refuses to render. However, now it's throwing a new error. I'll update the OP.